# Broadcast messages with websockets and SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

I'm trying to understand how to publish/broadcast messages using websockets with Spring Boot to a Javascript application. All examples I can find are making use of a `StompJs` client - I however am unable to use `StompJs` in my client code, and I'm not sure my backend is correct which doesn't help.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/subscribe")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }

}
```

Just using a simple `@Scheduled` to produce the time every 5 seconds, and send it to the `time` topic (Well, I believe that's what it's doing...)

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class TimeSender {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter TIME_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

    private SimpMessagingTemplate broker;

    @Autowired
    public TimeSender(final SimpMessagingTemplate broker) {
        this.broker = broker;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void run() {
        String time = LocalTime.now().format(TIME_FORMAT);

        log.info("Time broadcast: {}", time);

        broker.convertAndSend("/topic/time", "Current time is " + time);
    }
}
```

There are a few points I'm a little confused about when trying to test this. Using the `Simple websocket client` plugin for Chrome, I have to add `websocket` to the end of my request in order to connect. A connection would like `ws://localhost:8080/subscribe/websocket` Without the `websocket` I can't connect, but I can't find this mentioned in any examples or Spring documentation?

The second question is how do I subscribe to the time topic? All `StompJs` clients call something like `client.subscribe("time")` etc.

I've tried `ws://localhost:8080/subscribe/topic/time/websocket` but no luck in receiving any timestamps.

I'm not sure if my backend code is just wrong, my URL is wrong, or I'm just missing something else.

**Note**: My `@Controller` is missing from above as I'm just focused on pushing messages from Spring to clients at this stage, not receiving messages and It's my understanding controllers just deal with incoming?

Comment: Did you happen to resolve this? I am running into a similar problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I suppose if one searches obsessively enough the answer eventually turns up. Almost immediately after finding your post I found the answer I needed at http://www.marcelustrojahn.com/2016/08/spring-boot-websocket-example/. There is a really good example that essentially does what you are describing. The difference is they are using a Spring SimpMessagingTemplate to send messages to the queue. Once I followed his pattern, it all worked like a charm. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
@Autowired
SimpMessagingTemplate template

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 20000L)
@SendTo("/topic/pingpong")
public void sendPong() {
   template.convertAndSend("/topic/pingpong", "pong (periodic)")
}
```

The method is `void` so the `convertAndSend()` method handles publishing to the topic, not the return statement as just about every other tutorial I've seen on the web indicates. This helped solve my problem.